# Help with TIKZ drawing and shading regions limited by a curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, drawing

I need to create the picture below in Tikz. I cannot shade the two asymmetric regions as depicted. Any help is much appreciated.[image]

Comment: Welcome ;) // Please add the code you have so far to your question. Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you want, but hopefully this will get you started. Use the `patterns` library to get the diagonal lines. Use `\path` to form the boundary of each region including `plot` for the curve. (I used 1/√x for the function.) Then `\draw` the function and dashed lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[pattern=north west lines] (1,2.5)--(1,1) -- plot[domain=1:3.5, smooth] (\x,{1/sqrt(\x)}) -- (3.5,2.5) -- cycle;
\path[pattern=north east lines] (.5,0)--(.5,{1/sqrt(.5)}) -- plot[domain=.5:3.5, smooth] (\x,{1/sqrt(\x)}) -- (3.5,0) -- cycle;
\draw(0,3)--(0,-.5) (-.5,0)--(4,0);
\draw[domain=.15:3.5, smooth] plot (\x,{1/sqrt(\x)});
\draw[dashed](1,0)--(1,2.5) (.5,0)--(.5,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you want to color the regions, you don't need `patterns`, just `\fill` the regions with colors of your choosing.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue] (1,2.5)--(1,1) -- plot[domain=1:3.5, smooth] (\x,{1/sqrt(\x)}) -- (3.5,2.5) -- cycle;
\fill[red] (.5,0)--(.5,{1/sqrt(.5)}) -- plot[domain=.5:3.5, smooth] (\x,{1/sqrt(\x)}) -- (3.5,0) -- cycle;
\draw(0,3)--(0,-.5) (-.5,0)--(4,0);
\draw[domain=.15:3.5, smooth] plot (\x,{1/sqrt(\x)});
\draw[dashed](1,0)--(1,2.5) (.5,0)--(.5,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! What if I want to replace the slanted lines with a uniform colour in each region?

Comment: @Marg: I updated my response.

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted, thank you very much.

Comment: @Marg Accept the Sandy's answer!

Comment: @Marg: It may seem strange, but on this site we generally don't thank users for their posts. The way we show appreciation is by [upvoting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) when you have sufficient reputation, and [accepting the answer that you find most helpful](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), which you can do regardless of reputation.